# Using include pattern for gitlfs repo gives: batch response: Repository or object not found:

Tags: security, repository, artifactory, git-lfs

I want to use an include pattern for our git-lfs Artifactory repository to make separate directory's for security reasons.

The default directory created in the git-lfs repo is objects.
I want to place the artifacts in nl/kadaster/xxxx directory structures.
But when I push the artifacts using git push ( configured for pushing some type of artifacts to Artifactory ) I get an error:

batch response: Repository or object not found: http://'artifacthostname'/artifactory/api/lfs/lfs-local/nl/kadaster/dev/objects/batch
Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://'githostname'/dev/gitlfs-test'

Pushing to the 'default' git-lfs root dir is ok. ( when I remove the include pattern in de repo configuration in artifactory )

I have tried several configurations in .get/config and .lfsconfig

I want to be able to push the artifacts to separate directory's in the Artifactory git-lfs repository.